# Generate almost random file name in Python

Tags: python

I have

```
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
     return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
r = id_generator()
bat = open('MS-%s.bat',"w")%(r)
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

Comment: BTW, there is a uuid module http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html, which i usefull, when you want a unique id.

Comment: You can also use library 'tempfile' http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misplace, you should have written it like this:

```
    bat = open('MS-%s.bat' % (r), "w")
```

Comment: beat you by 4 seconds :)

Comment: But I think if you really want to be pedantic PEP8 would recommand the spaces

Comment: @Nirk: beat with what? Without explanations both your answers are pretty useless.

Comment: @thg435 in this case, it appears to be a typo.  There's no evidence to suggest it was anything more, and as such no additional explanation is necessary.

Comment: @Nirk: his question was "why doesn't this work" and you haven't answered that.

Comment: @thg435 "there's a typo" is a valid answer to "why doesn't this work?"  (because the OP didn't actually implement what he intended to do)

Comment: This is what i did. It worked out just fine. i understand why it doesnt work now, (my understanding may be inaccurate but). Its because open('string for name', 'args') , i was putting the % stuff where the arguments for initalization go. It makes sense it should be by the name of the file before the W. Exactly the output i wanted. No tempfile or other modules ty.

Answer (score 3):

While the existing answers are technically correct, why not use the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module instead. It handles the name collisions etc. correctly already.

And you can define `dir` and `suffix` so creating `.bat` files in some directory would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to say

```
bat = open('MS-%s.bat'%(r),"w")
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be:

```
bat = open('MS-%s.bat' % r ,"w")
```

Because the substitution of r belongs to MS-%s.bat.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `.format` function instead of `%` operator. Taken from doc:

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.

So you can modify your code:

```
bat = open('MS-{0}.bat'.format(r),"w")
```